# Is A Datetime Column's Value the Default One

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table and a column of type datetime. It's default value is something like 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

How do I check if a given row's value on this datetime column is the above by using native MySQL query functionality. E.g. without using "SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_date<>'0000-00-00 00:00:00'", because this leaves room for errors on different MySQL servers and configurations I believe.

Comment: You should work on your acccept rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_date <> 0
```

You can test it with

```
select cast('0000-00-00 00:00:00' as datetime) = 0
```

which returns `true` (and `false` for all other `datetime` values).

Comment: So if a column has a default value (no matter what this default value is), the column<>0 will check if it's not this value?

Comment: No. If the default of your datetime column is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` then you can check with `<>0`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_date > '1970-01-01 00:00:00". 1/1/1970 is the commonly used epoch date.